# Openshift Online persistance storage

Tags: openshift

I am looking for a way to store user uploads and around 500mb of images on Openshift online. 
Looked into the DATA folder but that should only be used for non-scalable app.
The app is not enterprise so I can't use kubernetes.
Is storing images of user uploads in DATA folder safe?

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to store your data anywhere in the container including your source folders, unless you package them as part of your app. Anytime your POD is killed or a new pod started it will default to what is originally included in your build src.